# Where should I create user in SPA using Oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, single-page-application

I am working on an application with spring boot backend, that I want to secure with OAuth2 using implicit flow. The front end will be angular (SPA). For the initial phase I will have Authorization and Resource server on the same instance, but want to be able to seperate it later on.

I do understand that authorization "takes place" on the Authorization server and then a token is used to access resources. But how do I add a new user to the system? Should there be a registration (password reset etc.) endpoint on Authorization server or the Resource Server?
It makes sense to put it on Authorization server, so when I add a new application that uses it will be able to add a new user to the system.
From other point of view the Authorization server should be used only for authorization, so user creation could be delegated to a resource server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the registration process is implemented in the resource server, so this endpoint and similar endpoints like retrieving a forgotten password, resetting the password etc all of them lives in the resource server, as they are part of the logic of your application, not part of the authorisation itself.

Comment: Thanks it makes sense. User is just a resource from resource server perspective and used for authorization from authorization server perspective